# How to send normal remote notification using PushKit iOS8?

Tags: ios8, push-notification

I have read about PushKit framework in apple document. In this document the have told that PushKit is used for sending push of two types:

1. VoIP push
2. Standard Push

But i could get only one desiredPushTypes of `PKPushRegistry`,which is "PKPushTypeVoIP".. But I am in need to send standard push using PushKit.. Can anyone help me with sample code how to send standard push using PushKit?

Thanks.

Comment: *This is a preliminary document for an API or technology in development.* In short, it's not ready to use yet.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this option designed only for very special cases. Currently, after WatchOS 2 released they've added ClockKit Complications as possible destination.
So, there is still no 'normal' destination for PushKit notifications.
Currently only VoIP and Apple Watch Complications.